# TimePickerFragment .show() error - Android

Tags: android, mobile

I'm getting a really strange error with a TimePickerFragment object I've created in my Android app and was hoping someone could help me out a bit. The code where the object is created is as follows:

```
public void showTimePickerFragment(View v){
    TimePickerFragment newFrag = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

For some reason I'm getting an error on .show(). The error message I have is:

```
The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)
```

I'm not sure if I'm just overlooking something here but that's a really confusing error message to me. I've tried changing "getFragmentManager()" to "getSupportFragmentManager()" but that causes an error with the arguments!

I've also already imported all the classes I need for this app, so it isn't a problem with that.

If anyone needs to see more code I can totally post it here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks all!

Comment: That is most likely happening because you don't use the correct imports. Make sure you either use only the classes from the compatibility packages or the normal ones. You might want to add the code for the `TimePickerDialog`.

Comment: Ahhhh yes...I'm stupid. I had imported the incorrect class for it all...if you want to copy that response into the answer section I'll be sure to check it off. Considering it solved my problem haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from not using the right imports for the classes(so the method expects a different type then the one you provide). Make sure you either use use only the classes from the compatibility package or the normal ones from the android SDK.